# member.guild.roles.cache.add is not a function , While giving a role

Tags: discord, discord.js

What i am trying to achieve is having a very simple bot to give roles to people who have the role and only give it if the person they are mentioning has the role, Here is a example of what i mean;

Person1:hey i have a infected role

Person2:I dont have the infected role

Person2:blahblahblah @Person1 blahblahblah

and now Person2 Should get the infected role, But everytime someone pings someone else with the infected role i get errors, This is the current code i have;

```java
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login('i have my token here but i removed it for the question');

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
console.log("logging in")

client.user.setActivity(`discord.gg/ypj9PSx`, {
type: "STREAMING",
url: "https://www.twitch.tv/ninja"})
    .then(presence => console.log(`Your Status has been set to  ${presence.game ? presence.game.none : 'none'}`))
    .catch(console.error);
});
console.log("setting status")

client.on("message", message => {
   const infectionStarted = true
   const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'infected')
   
   
   const member = message.mentions.members.first()

   
   if (member) {
      
      member.guild.roles.cache.add(role)
   }   
})
```

But when i run this code it gives this error;

```java
TypeError: member.guild.roles.cache.add is not a function
at Client.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:28:32)
    at Client.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.3.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.3.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.3.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.3.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.3.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/ws/7.3.1/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/ws/7.3.1/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:797:20)
```

If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why the c++ tag?

Answer (score 1):

[`GuildMemberRoleManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) is a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), which has no method called `add`.

What you are looking for, is the method [`add`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) of [`GuildMemberRoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager).

---

```js
member.roles.add(role)
```

*Note: With `member.guild.roles.cache` you are actually accessing the cache of [`RoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=cache). (The member's guild roles, which obviously you don't want to.)*